# Attach a * to my DIv on click of the checkBox in JQuery

Tags: jquery, checkbox

I'm new to JQUery. If I checked the `checkBox` as required, I need to get a * to a div.

```
    <label class='Label3'>Options
    <input id='option1' class='checkbox' type='checkbox'></input><label class='choice' for='checkbox'>Required</label>
    <input id='option2' class='checkbox' type='checkbox'></input><label class='choice' for='checkbox'>No duplicates</label>
    </label>
```

If I selected the `option1` then I need to get a * Attached to my Div that is already generated before this. How can I do this?

Comment: What do you mean by "need to get a *" ?

Answer (score 2):

All you should need is the onclick event.

```
$('#option1').click(function() {
  if (this.checked) {
     $('#targetDiv').text('*');
  } else {
     $('#targetDiv').text('');
  }
});
```

[See this example.](http://jsbin.com/eroxo)

Comment: I need to attach a * to the top of the Div

Comment: I sure did, and the this should have been slightly different as well. Posting the example. (Hadn't tested it Yet)

Comment: In the example I use a span. A span makes more sense than a div, because you probably want it to be inline with the text of the question.

Comment: If you want the div where it appends the *, then look at this example: http://jsbin.com/ataje The downside to this approach is you'll have to insure that the state of the * in the div is consistent with the checkbox. The span approach always works because it's wholly replacing the state of the span whereas the div makes an assumption that when it adds the star, it didn't have a star already (say at page load). Sure, you could add a check, but seems like a lot more complicated solution than the span.